# JMeter - how to get test group's max loops?

Tags: jmeter

I want to get the max number of loops in the test group. But how?

I do not see anything to do with loops here

`JMeterContextService.getContext().getThreadGroup()`

Answer (score 1):

Number of loops is not about the Thread Group, it is property of the underlying [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/control/LoopController.html) so you need to amend your code like:

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().getSamplerController().getProperty('LoopController.loops')
```

Demo (assumes using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)):

[image: JMeter Get Thread Group Loop Count]

More information on scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [convention of setting loop count as a property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#using_variables) for example using `${__P(loopCount)}`. Then get the property number with default in groovy:

```
 props.get("loopCount", "1") as Integer
```

This is assuming you call JMeter with [overriding property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override), for example:

```
 jmeter -n -t -JloopCount=6 my.jmx
```