# How to get total loop count in JMeter using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want to get total number of loop count in assertions.
Let I have set loop count 6, then I should get total loop count value 6

```
int totalLoopCount = vars.getIteration();
```

Its giving me running loop count value i.e
1
2
3
4
5
6

I want total loop count value 6. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413141/jmeter-how-to-get-test-groups-max-loops ?

Comment: I am not using loop controller and please see attached image.

Comment: The link explain how to get the thread group number of loop with 2 answers/ways

Comment: Is this(LoopController.loops) a variable defined in global variable file ? How to set the total loop count with property or variable?

Comment: props.get("loopCount", "1") as Integer        -- What does static 1 and loopcount means?

Comment: ${__P(loopCount)}    -- Where you have defined this propery in your code(ln your provided link) ?

Comment: If you call JMeter with property as `jmeter -n -t -JloopCount=6 my.jmx`. see https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override , updated my answer

Comment: jmeter -n -t -JloopCount=6 my.jmx   where are you defining this variable (or file name) ?

Comment: my.jmx   I think it is your JMX test file.

Comment: Can you please let me know where you have defined properties in Jmeter?

Comment: in command line when starting jmeter, need to add `-JloopCount=6`

Comment: I am new to Property, so can you please let me know where to set Property in jmeter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter - how to get test group's max loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413141/jmeter-how-to-get-test-groups-max-loops)

Comment: Thanks user7294900. I appreciate your help. I have resolved this by using Global variables and set the loop count with that variable and retrieved the same variable value. Following is the code: int totalLoopCount = vars.get("loopCount") as Integer;

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like:

```
def loops = ctx.getThreadGroup().getSamplerController().getProperty('LoopController.loops')
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Get Thread Group Loops Number]

`ctx` is a shorthand for [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html), see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields.

You might also be interested in [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)